# libgdx memory allocaton fail on animations

Tags: android, libgdx

I am working on a libgdx project ,An animation object that extends an actor is triggered from my screen ,It works fine for animations having less than 50 frames ,but when I try to initialize my animation object with higher number of frames ,the app crashes and the error message stated below is displayed if I rerun the animation the app crashes, I have tried disposing the atlas once used.This is the animation class I am using.

```
public class AnimatedFullScreen extends Actor {
public boolean startAnimation = true;
public Sound sound;
private OnAnimationComplete mOnAnimationCompleterListener;
private Animation<TextureRegion> animation;
private TextureAtlas atlas;
private float scaleX, scaleY;
private float px = 0, py = 0;
private float animationWidth, animationHeight;
private int type = 0;
private float showTime;
private boolean loop;public AnimatedFullScreen(String atlasName) {
    atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("animations/sceneatlas/"+atlasName+"/"+atlasName+".atlas"));
    this.animation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.2f / 10f, atlas.getRegions());
    this.scaleX = CommonObjects.screenWidth / atlas.getRegions().get(0).getRegionWidth();
    this.scaleY = CommonObjects.screenHeight / atlas.getRegions().get(0).getRegionHeight();
    this.loop = false;
    this.px = 0;
    this.py = 0;
    this.startAnimation = true;
    this.type = 0;
    this.animationWidth =CommonObjects.screenWidth ;
    this.animationHeight = CommonObjects.screenHeight;

}
@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
    showTime += delta;
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {


    if (startAnimation) {

        batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(showTime, loop), px, py, 0, 0,
                type == 0 ? animation.getKeyFrame(showTime).getRegionWidth() : animationWidth,
                type == 0 ? animation.getKeyFrame(showTime).getRegionHeight() : animationHeight,
                type == 0 ? scaleX : scaleY,
                type == 0 ? scaleY : scaleY, 0);
    }

    //shows still image when animation not started
    else {
        batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(0, loop), px, py, 0, 0,
                type == 0 ? animation.getKeyFrame(showTime).getRegionWidth() : animationWidth,
                type == 0 ? animation.getKeyFrame(showTime).getRegionHeight() : animationHeight,
                type == 0 ? scaleX : scaleY,
                type == 0 ? scaleY : scaleY, 0);
    }

    //fires listener when animation completed
    if (animation.isAnimationFinished(showTime)) {
        if (mOnAnimationCompleterListener != null) {
            atlas.dispose();
            Gdx.app.log("ssa","ddss");
            mOnAnimationCompleterListener.setNextScreen();
        }
    }

}

public void setListener(OnAnimationComplete listener) {
    mOnAnimationCompleterListener = listener;
}}
```

this is the error log

> 07-11 11:51:10.209 28389-28485/? W/Adreno-GSL: : sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
>   07-11 11:51:10.233 28389-28485/? E/Adreno-GSL: : GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.

Comment: What's your atlas size in pixels?

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical limit on the number of frames allowed for an animation in libGDX. The only limit is memory. So, if you are having memory allocation errors, then you have too many objects overall. You should consider optimizing your animation to lower the number of frames, or optimize the sprites involved to lower memory.  Also check all of your other graphics that are being used to see if you can optimize the graphics.  You didn't mention if you are, but if you aren't, make sure to use sprite sheets to help with memory usage.  Try to minimize amount of wasted space to lower memory usage as well.

Comment: is there any way to increase memory allocation and what would be the ideal texture format that could help?

Comment: no, you cannot change memory allocation, as it is java. the VM handles that.  As for texture format, depends on your needs.  Color depth of the textures is important.  RBG8888 is full 24 bit color with transparency.  You can lower the color depth to improve memory, but it may not look as good.